# $G$ contains a normal $p$-Sylow subgroup and $p$ divides the order of the center

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I am looking at the following:

Let $G$ be a non-abelian finite group with center $|Z|>1$. 
I want to show that if $G/Z$ is a $p$-group, for some prime $p$, then $G$ contains a normal $p$-Sylow subgroup and $p\mid |Z|$.

$$$$

I have done the following:

Since $G/Z$ is a $p$-group, it contains $p$-Sylow subgroups, say $P$. 
From the correspondence theorem we have that there is a bijective mapping between the subgroups of $G$ that contain $Z$ and the subgroups of $G/Z$, 
$$\phi (A)\mapsto A/Z, \ A\in G$$ 
So, the corresponding $p$-Sylow of $G$ exists and it is the $PZ$.

Is this correct?

$$$$

We have that $|G/Z|=p^n$, for some $n$.

So, $\frac{|G|}{|Z|}=p^n \Rightarrow |Z|=\frac{|G|}{p^n}$.

Since $G$ contains a $p$-Sylow sybgroup we have that $|G|=p^ma$, where $p\not\mid a$.

So, we have to show that $m\geq n$, or not?

How could we show that?

Comment: If $|G|/|Z| = p^n$ and $|G|=p^ma$ with $p \not| a$,, then clearly $m \ge n$.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, why is $PZ$  a $p$-group? It might not be so you cannot answer like this.

Hint : You should try to consider the action of conjugation of $G$ on its $p$-Sylows.

> Consider the action of conjugation of $G$ on its $p$-Sylows. You know (from the second theorem of Sylow) that this action is transitive. But this action of conjugation factors naturally (since $Z$ acts trivially by conjugation) through $G/Z$. Let $n_p$ be the number of $p$-Sylows, from the second theorem of Sylow $n_p=1$ mod $p$. Since $G/Z$ is a $p$-group the number of fixed elements of $G/Z$ acting on the $p$-Sylows is congruent to $n_p$ mod $p$. In particular, there is a fixed $p$-Sylow for the action of $G/Z$ whence of $G$. By transitivity there cannot but be only one $p$-Sylow.

For the second question, you should use what you have already done.

Hint : Let $P$ be the unique $p$-Sylow. Assume that $|Z|$ is prime to $p$ then $P\cap Z$ is trivial. Using the fact that $G/Z$ is a $p$-group, show that $G=Z\times P$ and find an element in $G$ which is central but not in $Z$ (which is a contradiction).

> If $|Z|$ is prime to $p$, since $G/Z$ is a $p$-group we have an isomorphism of group between $G/Z$ and $P$. Since $Z$ and $P$  are both normal subgroups of $G$, with trivial intersection and generating $G$, we have $G=Z\times P$. Finally the center of $P$ is not trivial (since it is a $p$-group) so $Z(G)=Z\times Z(P)\neq Z=Z(G)$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

$PZ$ may not be Sylow-$p$ subgroup of $G$ (take $G=\mathbb{Z}_3\times Q_8$.)

The hypothesis *$G/Z$ is a $p$-group* implies that $G$ is nilpotent. In nilpotent groups, all Sylow subgroups are normal, and so $G$ is direct product of them. Since center of a $p$-group is non-trivial, this almost completes your expectation (fill up the details).

Comment: Why does it imply from the fact that $G/Z$ is a $p$-group that $G$ is nilpotent?

Comment: What is nilpotent group? Start with group $G$; factor it by its center, call new group $G_1=G/Z(G)$. Factor new group by its center, call it $G_2$ ... If this process ends to $1$ in $k$ steps, $G$ is said to be nilpotent of class $k$. For ex. if $G$ would abelian factoring it by its center (which is whole $G$) gives $1$; so in one step, we reach to $1$, $G$ is nilpotent of class $1$. Coming to your question in comment: it is well-known that *$p$-groups always have non-trivial center*. Thus, if $G/Z$ is $p$-group, factoring by its center will reduce order, and we certainly reach to identity.